# inheritance and init pattern with asyncio in python

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, python-asyncio

Searching the web i could not find a lot of answers regarding classes and init-patterns in python for inheritance. I would like to use something like the following pattern. Are there any disadvantages for this pattern? One maybe is that there could be no init method for the child.

```
import asyncio


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.something = None

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls, something):
        self = cls()
        self.something = something
        return self


class FooChild(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        #...
        super().__init__()

    @classmethod
    async def create(cls, something):
        self = await super().create(something)
        #...
        return self




async def main():
    something = "something"
    foo = await FooChild.create(something)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `self = cls()` in `Foo.create`? As written, `FooChild.create` will return an instance of `Foo`, not of `FooChild`.

Comment: You are right. This example did not work correctly. I changed the example so it will return the correct instance.

Comment: Note that you don't need the `createself`, you could just use `self = cls()`. Python doesn't encourage deep hierarchies of "virtual" calls, you don't gain anything by complicating your code.

Comment: Thank you, i did not understand that self=cls() is equivalent to the instantiation - changed example again